# Bind ajax call back in rails 2.3.11 using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a remote_form_for. Now *:onclick* I want to disable the submit button and on *ajax:complete* I want to enable the buttons back.

*:onclick* disable is working fine, but enable it back using *ajax:complete* event is not working.

Any thoughts?

Here comes the code,

```
(function(jQuery){
    jQuery.fn.disableWith = function(options){
        var settings = jQuery.extend({
            disable_event : function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }, options);

    this.bind('click', function(){
        jQuery(this).click(settings.disable_event);
    });
    this.bind("ajax:complete", function(){
        jQuery(this).unbind('click', settings.disable_event);
    });

    return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong event - try `ajaxComplete` :

```
this.bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
    jQuery(this).unbind('click', settings.disable_event);
});
```

[Docs on Ajax Events](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events)

Comment: if you put an `alert();` or `console.log()` in the event function - is the event even firing ?

Comment: It is not going inside the event. So alert(); or console.log() is not giving any output. If I submit the form using jquery ajax function call **"ajaxComplete"** is working fine.